# How solve for a variable given a condition in Python?

Tags: python

I have a code that solves a hydrostatic solar atmosphere.

```
import numpy as np

B_0 = 0.02 # base magnetic field [T]
p_0 = 0.015 # base pressure [J/m^-3]
h_D = 7.5E7 # dipole depth [m]
R_sol = 6.96E8 # solar radius [m]
M_sol = 1.9891E30 # solar mass [kg]
G = 6.673E-11 # gravitational constant [m^3 kg^-1 s^-2]
μ = 0.61 # mean molecular weight of solar corona
m_H = 1.6726E-27 # mass of H particle [kg]
μ_0 = (4*np.pi)*pow(10,-7) # permeability [H/m]
k = 1.3806e-23 # boltzmann constant [J/K]
T = 1e6 # temperature [K]

g = (G*M_sol)/(pow(R_sol,2))

lambda_p = (k*T)/(μ*m_H*g)    

def p(h):
    return p_0*exp(-h/lambda_p)

def B(h):
    return B_0*pow((1 + (h/h_D)), -3)

def β(h):
    return p(h)/(B(h)^2 / (2*μ_0) )
```

I am not very familiar with using iterative/numerical methods and was wondering if there was a way to determine the value of `h` when `β` = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get you started.

Looks like [`sympy`](http://sympy.org/) is what you need. It'll let you solve equations/functions pretty easily.

Install it with

```
pip install sympy
```

Then you can define `h` as a variable with `sympy.Symbol`

```
h = Symbol('h')
```

...and define your functions with `sympy.Lambda`:

```
p = Lambda(h, p_0*exp(-h/lambda_p))
B = Lambda(h, B_0*pow((1 + (h/h_D)), -3))
β = Lambda(h, p(h)/(B(h)**2 / (2*μ_0) ))
```

Then solve for `β(h) = 1`

```
βequals1 = β(h) - 1 # by default sympy solves for fn = 0, so fn = 1 needs to be rewritted as fn - 1 = 0
solutions = solveset(βequals1, h)
print(solutions)
```

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Lambda, solveset, exp

B_0 = 0.02 # base magnetic field [T]
p_0 = 0.015 # base pressure [J/m^-3]
h_D = 7.5E7 # dipole depth [m]
R_sol = 6.96E8 # solar radius [m]
M_sol = 1.9891E30 # solar mass [kg]
G = 6.673E-11 # gravitational constant [m^3 kg^-1 s^-2]
μ = 0.61 # mean molecular weight of solar corona
m_H = 1.6726E-27 # mass of H particle [kg]
μ_0 = (4*np.pi)*pow(10,-7) # permeability [H/m]
k = 1.3806e-23 # boltzmann constant [J/K]
T = 1e6 # temperature [K]

g = (G*M_sol)/(pow(R_sol,2))
lambda_p = (k*T)/(μ*m_H*g)    


h = Symbol('h')

p = Lambda(h, p_0*exp(-h/lambda_p))
B = Lambda(h, B_0*pow((1 + (h/h_D)), -3))
β = Lambda(h, p(h)/(B(h)**2 / (2*μ_0) ))

βequals1 = β(h) - 1 # by default sympy solves for fn = 0, so fn = 1 needs to be rewritted as fn - 1 = 0
solutions = solveset(βequals1, h) # set the domain parameter if you want also, like this solveset(βequals1, h, domain=S.Reals). Make sure to import S above if you do. S.Complex is default. See all options here: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#module-sympy.sets.fancysets
print(solutions)
```

The solution it gives is in the very long image below which you may want to click on to view:
[image: solution]

You also might want to look into something specifically designed for this, like [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). Or you could run it in a cloud platform for more computing power.

Comment: The example you provided here is super helpful. Still waiting for my program to stop running...

Comment: @Dila - Replacing `solve` with `solveset` solves the equation significantly faster. However it returns a set, so I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. Either way I've updated my answer accordingly.